# Balanced Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I need to build a balanced binary search tree. So far my program inserts the numbers from 1 to 26, but my program does not build it into a balanced binary search tree. If anyone could look at my code and help me out it would be much appreciated.

```
public class TreeNode {

  TreeNode leftTreeNode, rightTreeNode;// the nodes
  int data;
  //int size;



  public TreeNode(){//Constructer
    leftTreeNode = null;
    rightTreeNode = null;
  }

  public TreeNode(int newData){//Constructer with new Data coming in for comparison
    leftTreeNode = null;
    rightTreeNode = null;
    data = newData;
  }

  public TreeNode getLeft(){
    return leftTreeNode;
  }
  public TreeNode getRight(){
    return rightTreeNode;
  }

  public void setLeft(TreeNode leftTreeNode){
    this.leftTreeNode = leftTreeNode;
  }
  public void setRight(TreeNode rightTreeNode){
    this.rightTreeNode = rightTreeNode;
  }
  public int getData(){
    return data;
  }

//    public boolean isEmpty(){//Checking to see if the the root is empty
//      if(size == 0) return true;
//      else return false;



  public void print(){
    System.out.println("Data is: " + getData());
  }
}


//    public void traverse (Node root){ // Each child of a tree is a root of its subtree.
//    if (root.getLeft() != null){
//        traverse (root.getLeft());
//    }
//    System.out.println(root.data);
//    if (root.getRight() != null){
//        traverse (root.getRight());
//    }
//}









public class BinarySearchTree {
  TreeNode root;

  public BinarySearchTree(){
    root = null;
  }

  public TreeNode getRoot(){
    return root;
  }
  public void insert(int data) { //Insert method checking to see where to put the nodes
    TreeNode node1 = new TreeNode(data);
    if (root == null) { 
      root = node1; 
    } 
    else{
      TreeNode parIns = root;//Parent
      TreeNode insNode = root;//Insertion Node

      while(insNode != null){
        parIns = insNode;

        if(data < insNode.getData()){//If the data is less than the data coming in place it on the left
          insNode = insNode.getLeft();
        }else{//Place it on the right
          insNode = insNode.getRight();
        }
      }//Searching where to put the node

      if(data < parIns.getData()){
        parIns.setLeft(node1);
      }else{
        parIns.setRight(node1);
      }

    }
  }

  public void printInorder(TreeNode n){
    if(n != null){
      printInorder(n.getLeft());//L
      n.print();//N
      printInorder(n.getRight());//R
    }
  }
//    public TreeNode balance(tree, int start, int end){
//      if(start > end) return null;
//      int mid = (start + end) /2;
//      TreeNode node;
//      TreeNode leftChild;
//      TreeNode rightChild;
//      
//      if(node <= mid){
//        leftChild = balance(arr[mid -1], start, end);/*Make the left child if the node coming in is
//        less than the mid node */
//        
//        
//      }else{
//        rightChild = balance(arr[mid]+1, start, end);/*Make the rigth child if the node is
//          greater than the mid node*/
//        
//      }
//      return node;
//  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree();
    tree.insert(1);
    tree.insert(2);
    tree.insert(3);
    tree.insert(4);
    tree.insert(5);
    tree.insert(6);
    tree.insert(7);
    tree.insert(8);
    tree.insert(9);
    tree.insert(10);
    tree.insert(11);
    tree.insert(12);
    tree.insert(13);
    tree.insert(14);
    tree.insert(15);
    tree.insert(16);
    tree.insert(17);
    tree.insert(18);
    tree.insert(19);
    tree.insert(20);
    tree.insert(21);
    tree.insert(22);
    tree.insert(23);
    tree.insert(24);
    tree.insert(25);
    tree.insert(26);
    tree.printInorder(tree.getRoot());



  }



}



//for(int i = 1; i <= 26; i++)
  //tree.insert(i);


         public void balance(TreeNode tree, int start, int end){
      TreeNode tree1 = new TreeNode(data);
      if(start <= end){
      int mid = (start + end) /2;
      //TreeNode node;
      TreeNode leftChild;
      TreeNode rightChild;

      if(tree1.getData() <= mid){
        leftChild = balance(tree1(mid -1), start, end);/*Make the left child if the node coming in is
        less than the mid node */


      }else{
        rightChild = balance(tree1(mid+1), start, end);/*Make the rigth child if the node is
          greater than the mid node*/

      }

      }
}
```

How can I fix the balance function to properly balance my tree?

Comment: A plain binary search tree is not self-balancing. Your current code will essentially just create a linked list of values. Try looking into 2-3 trees or red-black trees.

Answer (score 4):

Since your tree does not self-balance, whether or not it's balanced will depend on the order of insertion of the elements.

If you want your tree to be balanced regardless, you will need to take care of the balancing in your class. For example, take a look at the [Red-Black Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) data structure.

Comment: Sorry it seems i like out most of my program haha but I just added the rest of what I have

Comment: The rest of what you've added doesn't change my answer. You have a primitive binary search tree which you never rebalance. Then you insert a bunch of numbers into it sequentially. Unless you either insert the elements in an order that will result in a balanced tree or programmatically balance the tree, it will not be balanced.

Comment: Yeah I understand that, that is what I need help with.

Comment: You need help with implementing a self-balancing tree? That's a non-trivial question. Look at the wikipedia article I linked. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree has more examples.

Answer (score -2):

```
public class BinarySearchTree {
  TreeNode root;

  public BinarySearchTree(){
    root = new TreeNode();
  }

  public TreeNode getRoot(){
    return root;
  }
  public void insert(int data) {
    root = insert(root, data);
  }//Insert method checking to see where to put the nodes

//  public void insert(TreeNode node, int data){
//    TreeNode node1 = new TreeNode(data);
//    if (root == null) { 
//      root = node1; 
//    } 
//    else{
//      TreeNode parIns = root;//Parent
//      TreeNode insNode = root;//Insertion Node
//      
//      while(insNode != null){
//        parIns = insNode;
//        
//        if(data < insNode.getData()){//If the data is less than the data coming in place it on the left
//          insNode = insNode.getLeft();
//        }else{//Place it on the right
//          insNode = insNode.getRight();
//        }
//      }//Searching where to put the node
//      
//      if(data < parIns.getData()){
//        parIns.setLeft(node1);
//      }else{
//        parIns.setRight(node1);
//      }
//      
//    }
//  }

  private TreeNode insert(TreeNode node, int data) { 
    if(root.data == 0)
      root.data = data;
    else if (node==null) { 
      node = new TreeNode(data); 
    } 
    else { 
      if (data <= node.data) { 
        node.leftTreeNode = insert(node.leftTreeNode, data); 
      } 
      else { 
        node.rightTreeNode = insert(node.rightTreeNode, data); 
      } 
    } 

    return(node); // in any case, return the new pointer to the caller 
  } 
  public void printPreOrder(){
    printPreOrder(root);
  }
  public void printPreOrder(TreeNode n){
    if(n != null){
      n.print();//N
      printPreOrder(n.getLeft());//L
      printPreOrder(n.getRight());//R
    }
  }

    public TreeNode balance(int[] a, int start, int end){
    TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
    if(start <= end){
      int mid = start + (end - start) /2;
      node.data = a[mid];

      if(root.data == 0)
        root = node;
      node.leftTreeNode = balance(a, start, mid -1);/*Make the left child if the node coming in is
       less than the mid node */


      node.rightTreeNode = balance(a, mid + 1, end);/*Make the rigth child if the node is
       greater than the mid node*/
    }
      else{
      return null;
      }


    return node;
  }



  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree();
    //int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,21,22,23,24,25,26};
    int[] a = new int[26];
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
      a[i] = i + 1;
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= 26; i++)
      tree.insert(i);

    tree.printPreOrder();
    BinarySearchTree tree2 = new BinarySearchTree();
    tree2.balance(a, 0, 25);
    System.out.println("Now I am going to balance my tree");
    tree2.printPreOrder();

  }

}



public class TreeNode {

  TreeNode leftTreeNode, rightTreeNode;// the nodes
  int data;
  //int size;



  public TreeNode(){//Constructer
    leftTreeNode = null;
    rightTreeNode = null;
    data = 0;
  }

  public TreeNode(int newData){//Constructer with new Data coming in for comparison
    leftTreeNode = null;
    rightTreeNode = null;
    data = newData;
  }

  public TreeNode getLeft(){
    return leftTreeNode;
  }
  public TreeNode getRight(){
    return rightTreeNode;
  }

  public void setLeft(TreeNode leftTreeNode){
    this.leftTreeNode = leftTreeNode;
  }
  public void setRight(TreeNode rightTreeNode){
    this.rightTreeNode = rightTreeNode;
  }
  public int getData(){
    return data;
  }


//    public boolean isEmpty(){//Checking to see if the the root is empty
//      if(size == 0) return true;
//      else return false;



  public void print(){
    System.out.println("Data is: " + getData());
  }


}
```